# Split values in a column synced to all other columns

Tags: r

I want to separate values in column c where there are >1 value. I have found that from tidyr you can use separate_rows but I can't make it work. Happy for suggestions to solve it!

```
a <- c("e","f","g")
b <- c(2,1,3)
c <- c(27,4,678)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df
 a b   c
 e 2  27
 f 2   4
 g 2 678
```

I want it to look like:

```
a b c
 e 2 2
 e 2 7
 f 1 4
 g 3 6
 g 3 7
 g 3 8
```

I have tried the following code from similar example but it doesn't work

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df,c, convert=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(c = strsplit(as.character(c), "")) %>%
 unnest()

  a b c
1 e 2 2
2 e 2 7
3 f 2 4
4 g 2 6
5 g 2 7
6 g 2 8
```

And probably you want to transform it back into a numeric vector:

```
df %>%
 mutate(c = strsplit(as.character(c), "")) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 mutate(c = as.numeric(c))
```

Comment: Ok thanks! And how could it be done if there would be many variables and I want to do this with a specific column? :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate how do you mean it?

Comment: For example, ha dataset like this, and I only want to do this function with column c. 

a <- c("e","f","g")
b <- c(2,2,2)
c <- c(27,4,678)
d <- c(45,6,78)
e <- c(4,78,92)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
df

Comment: You mean that you want to return only column `c` as a result?

Comment: Sorry it was me coding wrong, ignore my last question, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To do it via `separate_rows` you need to modify your delimiter, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 separate_rows(c, sep = '(?<=.)(?=.)')

#  a b c
#1 e 2 2
#2 e 2 7
#3 f 1 4
#4 g 3 6
#5 g 3 7
#6 g 3 8
```

Or for your new data frame,

```
df %>% 
 separate_rows(c, sep = '(?<=.)(?=.)')

#  a b c  d  e
#1 e 2 2 45  4
#2 e 2 7 45  4
#3 f 2 4  6 78
#4 g 2 6 78 92
#5 g 2 7 78 92
#6 g 2 8 78 92
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can read about how to use and interpret  '(?<=.)(?=.)'. How should I know how to write that to locate that position?